# AChartEngine TimeSeries XAxis Time grid Settings

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm trying to use the AChartEngine library using a time series. The X axis is time, and Y axis are integer values.

The problem is that I could not setup a renderer.setXAxisMin and Max for the X axis for time. Either all the data points are crumbed together, or the time is apart so large that I cannot see any datapoints.

This is the classes I've used:

```
    //For Chart 1
private static Random random = new Random();
private static TimeSeries timeSeries;
private static XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset;
private static XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer;
private static XYSeriesRenderer rendererSeries;
private static GraphicalView view;
```

Initialization:

```
    if(timeSeries == null)
    {
        //Chart 1
        dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        timeSeries = new TimeSeries("Channel 1");
        rendererSeries = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    }
```

Renderer:

```
    //For Chart 1
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitle("Real Time Seizure Monitoring Graph");
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(15);
    renderer.setFitLegend(true);
    renderer.setGridColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    renderer.setPointSize(1);
    renderer.setXTitle("Time");
    renderer.setYTitle("Amplitude (DAC)");
    renderer.setMargins( new int []{60, 60, 60, 60});
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(10);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    renderer.setPointSize(5);
    renderer.setXLabels(10);
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setInScroll(true);
    renderer.setXLabels(5);
    //renderer.setXAxisMin(0.00000001);
    //renderer.setXAxisMax(new Date().getTime());
    //renderer.setXAxisMin(100);
    //renderer.setXAxisMax(1000000);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(rendererSeries);
    rendererSeries.setFillPoints(true);
    rendererSeries.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    rendererSeries.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Adding the datasets and series:

```
    //Setting for Chart 1
    dataset.addSeries(timeSeries);
    view = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(this, dataset, renderer, "Real Time Seizure Monitoring Graph");
    view.refreshDrawableState();
    view.repaint();
```

Function to start inserting random variables:

```
void startTest()
{   
    mThread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000L);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Chart 1 Random Data
                int someInt = random.nextInt(4096);
                timeSeries.add(new Date(), someInt);
                timeSeries.addAnnotation(new Date().toString(), new Date().getTime(), someInt);
                view.refreshDrawableState();
                view.repaint();
            }
        }
    };
    mThread.start();
}
```

}

Without the set X axis min and max commented, the datapoints are updated with no problems, and all points are visible.

Furthermore, if there a lot of data points created by the thread, the panning appears to be very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X axis min should be some value around the first value that was added to the series. The X axis max should be some value around the last value in the series.

Anyway, it depends on the visible range you want to have in your chart. Setting a value of 100 as I see in one of your commented out line means that the minimum visible value on the X axis is in the year 1970, which makes all the values be crowded somewhere on the right side of the chart.

Comment: You were right! renderer.setXAxisMin(new Date().getTime()); did the trick. I kept having the year 1970 because I didn't know how to setup the grid correctly.